# Can't accept answers

Tags: support

Keep getting this when attempting to Accept and answer.

> An error has occurred - please try your request.

This has been happening for several weeks and I don't know why.

Question:
[C# ConvertTimeFromUtc funkiness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41819948/c-sharp-converttimefromutc-funkiness)

Attempting to accept ANY answer results in the error.

Comment: Anything come up in the browser console?

Comment: `http://stackoverflow.com/posts/41820134/vote/1 403 (Forbidden)`

Comment: That suggests that something is blocking the request - but not on the Stack Exchange side - possibly a firewall or a browser extension. Can you try over https?

Comment: I guess I'm going to have to run everything through https://www.stackoverflow.com now.. ;-)

Comment: Post that as answer to be accepted.

Comment: Tried again today and it didn't work on this URL even with https: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41600827/expression-lamda-with-known-type

Comment: Lo and behold, opened another window, set to https and it allowed accepting of answers. What gives???

Comment: Something is blocking some actions (either URLs or JavaScript) on your end. Either malware on your computer, or someone upstream from you (paranoid firewall rules? ISP shenanigans) - using HTTPS stops these man-in-the-middle issues.

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended to always use **HTTPS** to connect to the Stack Exchange Network.

---

According to [Oded](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/140505/oded) in the [following comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/290331/cant-accept-answers#comment942592_290331):

> That suggests that something is blocking the request - but not on the Stack Exchange side - possibly a firewall or a browser extension. Can you try over https?

Some additional details are provided in the [following comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/290331/cant-accept-answers#comment942665_290331) from [Oded](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/140505/oded):

> Something is blocking some actions (either URLs or JavaScript) on your end. Either malware on your computer, or someone upstream from you (paranoid firewall rules? ISP shenanigans) - using HTTPS stops these man-in-the-middle issues.

Comment: That's not really relevant anymore, since HTTPS is used anyway on all sites.

Comment: Specifically, HTTPS is *forced* for all vaguely modern browsers using redirects and Strict Transport Security. Nobody has the option of not using TLS these days.